# Python/Canopy - The Specified Module(s) Could Not Be Found

Tags: python, scipy

I'm new to Python and am looking to run a specific coding package that I've used with `MatLab`- it's also available on Python. I've downloaded `Canopy` but I keep getting the `The Specified Module(s) Could Not Be Found` error. It looks like the code is looking in the `Scipy Linalg` package, which is part of `Canopy`. I'm not entirely sure how to resolve the issue. Help would be appreciated. The error and traceback are as follows but quite lengthy. I've also included the same code as .jpgs if that is easier to read:

```
[ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ortizdav\Documents\Python\spm1d-master\spm1d-master\spm1d\examples\stats1d\ex_ttest2.py in <module>()
      1 
      2 from matplotlib import pyplot
----> 3 import spm1d
      4 
      5 
C:\Users\ortizdav\spm1d\__init__.py in <module>()
     29 from . import data
     30 from . import io
---> 31 from . import plot
     32 from . import rft1d
     33 from . import stats
C:\Users\ortizdav\spm1d\plot.py in <module>()
     31 
     32 import numpy as np
---> 33 from . _plot import DataPlotter, SPMPlotter, SPMiPlotter, _legend_manual
     34 
     35 
C:\Users\ortizdav\spm1d\_plot.py in <module>()
     12 from copy import copy,deepcopy
     13 import numpy as np
---> 14 from scipy import ndimage
     15 import matplotlib
     16 from matplotlib import pyplot, cm as colormaps
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py in <module>()
    159 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    160 
--> 161 from .filters import *
    162 from .fourier import *
    163 from .interpolation import *
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py in <module>()
     36 from . import _ni_support
     37 from . import _nd_image
---> 38 from . import _ni_docstrings
     39 from scipy.misc import doccer
     40 from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_ni_docstrings.py in <module>()
      2 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
      3 
----> 4 from scipy.misc import doccer
      5 
      6 __all__ = \['docfiller'\]
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py in <module>()
     66 from numpy import who as _who, source as _source, info as _info
     67 import numpy as np
---> 68 from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade
     69 from scipy.special import (comb as _comb, logsumexp as _lsm,
     70         factorial as _fact, factorial2 as _fact2, factorialk as _factk)
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py in <module>()
    173 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    174 
--> 175 from .interpolate import *
    176 from .fitpack import *
    177 
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in <module>()
     18                    dot, ravel, poly1d, asarray, intp)
     19 
---> 20 import scipy.linalg
     21 import scipy.special as spec
     22 from scipy.special import comb
C:\Users\ortizdav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py in <module>()
    205 from ._solvers import *
    206 from ._procrustes import *
--> 207 from ._decomp_update import *
    208 from ._sketches import *
    209 
_decomp_update.pyx in init scipy.linalg._decomp_update()
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found][1]
```

. [Same code as above but in image format if this is easier to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvgQ4.jpg)

Best,

```
David
```

Comment: Hmmm have you considered Anaconda? It used to be the go-to on Windows because of issues like this.

Comment: Anaconda worked out. Thank you!